# EF Core + SignalR multiple client: "Can not rollback - No transaction active"

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, entity-framework-core, database-concurrency

I am using EFCore SQLite with SignalR.

When there are many clients connect at the same time, database can not changes (insert/update) anymore, this exception throws: **"Can not rollback - No transaction active"**

A client connects with query param that contains its info, then:

- Look into the database, if clientName exists then update its info. Otherwise, add new.
- After connected, client name call GetData() that returns all clients info etc...
- There are about 100 clients connect at the same time.

Logs:

```
An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query.
System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.
```

Then

```
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 5: 'database is locked'.
```

After that, when I try to insert or update things:

```
Cannot rollback - No transaction is active
```

Is there a workaround? This only happens on production with 50 clients+, so it's hard to debug when development.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is not meant to be used as a server database. This is because only one insert/update can be performed at the same time.

It is better to use SQL Server, MySQL, Postgre or some other sql database server

http://sqlite.org/whentouse.html

> If there are many client programs sending SQL to the same database
>   over a network, then use a client/server database engine instead of
>   SQLite. SQLite will work over a network filesystem, but because of the
>   latency associated with most network filesystems, performance will not
>   be great. Also, file locking logic is buggy in many network filesystem
>   implementations (on both Unix and Windows). If file locking does not
>   work correctly, two or more clients might try to modify the same part
>   of the same database at the same time, resulting in corruption.
>   Because this problem results from bugs in the underlying filesystem
>   implementation, there is nothing SQLite can do to prevent it.
>
> A good rule of thumb is to avoid using SQLite in situations where the
>   same database will be accessed directly (without an intervening
>   application server) and simultaneously from many computers over a
>   network.